# JSON data to place markers in Google Maps

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I am trying to place markers according to coordinates that are placed in JSON, but I think I'm not doing things quiet right.

```
    public class Stadiums
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Team { get; set; }

    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}


public void GetStadiums()
    {
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NFLConnectionString"].ToString();

        List<Stadiums> matchingStadiums = new List<Stadiums>();
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {

            string oString = "Select * from Stadiums";
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    matchingStadiums.Add(new Stadiums
                    {
                        Team = oReader["Team"].ToString(),
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["ID"]),
                        Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(oReader["Latitude"]),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(oReader["Longitude"])
                    });
                }

                ResultstoJSON(matchingStadiums);

                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ResultstoJSON(List<Stadiums> stadiums)
    {
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(stadiums);
        this.JSONData = json;
    }
```

I have verified that JSONData contains all of the data I'm looking for in JSON format. From here, I don't know how to take the data and place pins in Google Maps.

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?     v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891)
        };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: (myLatlng),
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Link to JSON data: http://pastebin.com/cJBDi3ti

Again, to clarify, I am trying to place pins/markers in Google Maps according to the items in the JSON data(that have coordinates).

Comment: Please provide more information including a link to your JSON data or a JSfiddle with the Json in a string variable and Ill help you.

Comment: Do you have any specific question other  than `I'm not doing things quiet right. `

Comment: I added a pastebin link to the bottom of my post.

Comment: And my question is, how do I properly add pins to google maps according to the JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you provided and your JSON,

Your controller will need to return the json marker data to the client - currently your not returning anything.

In the client once you have the json parse it to an object:

```
var markerData = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then after you created your map - loop through each of the items in your markerData array and create a marker for it based on its Latitude and Longitudevalues:

```
$.each(markerData,function()
{
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.Latitude, this.Longitude);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: (myLatlng),
         data:this,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });                
}
```

Here is a JS fildle to help you

http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/4wtyqmrg/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by getting my controller to return the json marker data to the client?

Comment: Your marker data comes from the server right? So when returning it to the client (browser) you will return the json string.  Your code above does not show how you return the json to your browser.  If you have the json data in the browser then your fine and can follow the step I showed you above